# Facebook "Like" button for image

Tags: image, facebook, facebook-like

trying to get my "Like" button to link to Wordpress attached image URL.

Is it possible to "Like" just an image file?

Here's what I have

```
<?php $large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large'); ?>

<div class="likeButton" style="float: left;"><iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<?php echo urlencode($large_image_url); ?>&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=100&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:100px; height:25px"></iframe></div>
```

Firebug shows it's linking, but pressing like yileds no results to my FB page. Hewlp!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my answer here: [Like Button counts the likes of a PDF but does not actually post the activity?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/13615310/like-button-counts-the-likes-of-a-pdf-but-does-not-actually-post-the-activity/13616954#13616954)

You can't like a file directly because the file won't serve the metadata Facebook uses to display the 'like' story - you need to like a HTML URL, then include the image on that URL (or redirect users other than Facebook's crawler to the image)

Comment: Thank you for your timely and insightful answer sir.